# Send object from server to client and deserialize it c#

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization

Hello i am creating a server to transfer objects to parse it at the client and i can send the object but when i recieve it it crashes directly the client, my code is this:

```
public static byte[] SerializeToBytes<T>(T source)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                try
                {
                    formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Then i use this at the server connected to try to send something to test if works or not.

```
            DataTable dt = titlesTable.GetData();
            var t = new Title((koianimeDataSet.titlesRow)dt.Rows[0], "Gallery");
            _server.SendOne(SerializeToBytes(t),e.Connection);
```

To the client recieve it i havew this other code

```
public static T DeserializeFromBytes<T>(byte[] source)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(source))
            {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }

Title t = DeserializeFromBytes<Title>(e.SockMessage);
MessageBox.Show(t.GetTitleName(), "Info");
```

StackTrace

```
2017-12-20 09:55:18.783 [FATAL]      en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerializationHeaderRecord.Read(__BinaryParser input)
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadSerializationHeaderRecord()
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   en KoiAnme.MainWIndow.DeserializeFromBytes[T](Byte[] source) en C:\Users\detonatorss\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\KoiAnme\KoiAnme\MainWindow.xaml.cs:línea 171
   en KoiAnme.MainWIndow.Client_DataReceived(Object sender, SockMessageEventArgs e) en C:\Users\detonatorss\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\KoiAnme\KoiAnme\MainWindow.xaml.cs:línea 134
```

i am passing the object with this sockets library

https://github.com/nunobaraujo/NBsoft.Sockets

Comment: Please include the errormessage and stacktrace.

Comment: Are the two "Title" classes actually _the same_ class or just two classes that happen to have the same name and properties? (i.e. Is class "Title" from a shared assembly?)

Comment: are the same so it can deserialize no? or i am wrong?

Comment: Should. But you really need to add the error stacktrace to the question.

Comment: Added StackTrace